# Configure boost build on windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, bjam

I'm currently trying to build a subset of the boost libraries on my (Windows) machine. In the Linux world it seems to be possible that the desired libraries can be specified by

```
bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=lib1,lib2,...libn
```

I assumed that the Windows version bootstrap.bat would have the same command line options but I was wrong, it did not even react to `--help`. Is there a way to avoid building the whole project using the `bootstrap.bat` / `bjam.exe` / `b2.exe` approach?

EDIT: Looking into `bootstrap.bat` revealed that there are no command line options. It seems I have to configure `project-config.jam`. Currently, there is only one line telling me that it uses the msvc compiler.

Comment: Read the `bootstrap.bat` code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming (for no reason, I know) you are using VisualStudio 2005 (which is `msvc-8.0`) you can issue the commands

```
bootstrap
.\bjam toolset=msvc-8.0  --with-filesystem
```

to compile, e.g., filesystem

Hope it helps